# GLSL ES 2.0 alternative for dFdxFine

Tags: glsl, fragment-shader, webgl

I'm trying to generate normal map on the fly in fragment shader. The implementation I've found is using dFdxFine function, which can't be used in WebGL, is there any alternative for dFdxFine in GLSL ES 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use `dFdx` instead? You may need `#define GL_OES_standard_derivatives 1` in your shader as well.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why I need dFdxFine, I'm not that strong at math to understand the solution entirely. I've tried using dFfx and it produced really chunky and not smooth normal map, so I suppose it's needed for smoothness.

Comment: What happens if you blur the resulting map (with a rather small kernel) then? This is definately not the accurate way, but maybe it makes the result visually acceptable

Comment: Also, glHint( GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER_DERIVATIVE_HINT, x) where x is either GL_FASTEST or GL_NICEST should set the standard dFdx to either dFdxCoarse or dFdxFine, didn't test that though

Comment: I'm having the same problem as the OP - using just plain dFdx produces chunky results in some cases. For example, when warping textures based on computed normals, small differences in the normal values can produce large changes in the output color, so using dFdx creates an undesirable 'venetian blind' effect where alternating scanlines are shaded differently. I'd like to figure a way to enable fine-grained derivatives in my shader code.